ERROR: Unknown compiler(s): [['ifort'], ['gfortran'], ['flang-new'], ['flang'], ['pgfortran'], ['g95']] What can I do?
When I tried to install a package pyADAqsar in jupyter notebook (python) using !pip install pyADAqsar, I always get this error. Does anyone know why I got this error? Thank you very much for your help!!!
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [45 lines of output]
  + meson setup C:\Users\zth3\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-install-gqijigts\scipy_fa508f38b953480899dcfb165ee84ff5 C:\Users\zth3\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-install-gqijigts\scipy_fa508f38b953480899dcfb165ee84ff5\.mesonpy-fl5xvbb5 -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --native-file=C:\Users\zth3\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-install-gqijigts\scipy_fa508f38b953480899dcfb165ee84ff5\.mesonpy-fl5xvbb5\meson-python-native-file.ini
  The Meson build system
  Version: 1.6.0
  Source dir: C:\Users\zth3\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-install-gqijigts\scipy_fa508f38b953480899dcfb165ee84ff5
  Build dir: C:\Users\zth3\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-install-gqijigts\scipy_fa508f38b953480899dcfb165ee84ff5\.mesonpy-fl5xvbb5
  Build type: native build
  Project name: SciPy
  Project version: 1.9.3
  Activating VS 17.11.5
  C compiler for the host machine: cl (msvc 19.41.34123 "Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.41.34123 for x64")
  C linker for the host machine: link link 14.41.34123.0
  C++ compiler for the host machine: cl (msvc 19.41.34123 "Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.41.34123 for x64")
  C++ linker for the host machine: link link 14.41.34123.0
  Host machine cpu family: x86_64
  Host machine cpu: x86_64
  Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-but-set-variable: NO
  Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-but-set-variable: NO (cached)
  Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-function: NO
  Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-conversion: NO
  Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-misleading-indentation: NO
  Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-incompatible-pointer-types: NO
  Library m found: NO
  
  ..\meson.build:57:0: ERROR: Unknown compiler(s): [['ifort'], ['gfortran'], ['flang-new'], ['flang'], ['pgfortran'], ['g95']]
  The following exception(s) were encountered:
  Running `ifort --help` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  Running `ifort --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  Running `ifort -V` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  Running `gfortran --help` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  Running `gfortran --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  Running `gfortran -V` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  Running `flang-new --help` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  Running `flang-new --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  Running `flang-new -V` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  Running `flang --help` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  Running `flang --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  Running `flang -V` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  Running `pgfortran --help` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  Running `pgfortran --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  Running `pgfortran -V` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  Running `g95 --help` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  Running `g95 --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  Running `g95 -V` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  
  A full log can be found at C:\Users\zth3\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-install-gqijigts\scipy_fa508f38b953480899dcfb165ee84ff5\.mesonpy-fl5xvbb5\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

Encountered error while generating package metadata.

See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

I tried to download VS c++ build tools and also tried to upgrade pip using !py -m pip install --upgrade pip. However, both of these are not working.

It looks like the library expects you to have a fortran compiler installed, just as you have a C compiler installed.

Since you're building scipy from source, I would recommend that you read the documentation about building from source. That explains how to get ifort, gfortran, etc.

What Python version are you using?

@AndrewNelson I am using python 3.12.3. Thanks

You shouldn't have to build scipy from source on windows. Can you just pip install scipy? It should install a binary wheel, not build from source.

Hi @ev-br, I used !pip install scipy in jupyter notebook successfully, but I had above error when I  was using !pip install pyADAqsar

Can you import scipy successfully? I wonder if the other package wants a different version.
